# Displaying an object's true color inside another object

Tags: materials

Let's assume object B is inside object A. Object A is colored transparently. Object B is also colored.

Now as you may easily guess, object B would be visible, but its color would appear different, more pale than its true color, because it is within object A, which is transparent.

My question is, is it possible to display the real color of object B as if it was not inside object A, without changing anything about Object A's coloring and transparency and still keeping object B inside object A?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, shader wise. Take a look at "Light path" node. Another solution would be to render 2 layers and composite them together. Simpler but a bit more render time.